# c# Writing a .Xlsx file to byte[] save it to a SQL database and then retrieve and open it again just gets corrupted

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

As per the title I am trying to save and retrieve .xlsx files (as well as any other formats the user may upload) to a SQL database and then retrieve them to be opened in the native application.

I have the code that I am currently trying to get to work. I have narrowed it down to the saving and loading of the byte[]. I can't seem to find a good way to do this in c#.

Below is what I have but it just opens the file and I get a message "Excel cannot open the file "Book1.xlsx" because the file format or extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Note: The code below works fine with images and other formats.

```
     private byte[] _fileArray;
    private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _fileArray = ReadFully(stream);
        }

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newFolder = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

        string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(newFolder.FullName, "Book1.xlsx");


        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(tempFileName))
        {
            FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(tempFileName) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary /* optimises by holding in memory*/ };

            stream.Write(_fileArray, 0, _fileArray.Length);

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = tempFileName;
            //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            proc.Start();
            proc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the database has to do with your question, nor the C# 7 tag. From the code you've provided, the most likely problem is that you are not closing the stream before trying to load it into Excel.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of most of tat stream reading and writing code by just using `File.ReadAllBytes()` and `File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: @David Sorry for using the wrong tag, I was just making sure that it was in the correct area. You are correct in that the stream needed closing in order to open the file correctly.


I have also rewritten the code so that it now only uses File.ReadAllBytes and File.WriteAllBytes 


Thanks very much for the answer!